# Scrolling through multiple DIV elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example let's say that I have a div element with `100%` width and `100px` height. Inside that div I have 6 div elements floated left, with `overflow-x` enabled. What I want to achieve is, that user can scroll through loop of these divs (so that last div element is followed by first - infinite loop).

Any idea how to approach?

[image]

Comment: You're describing a classical slider functionality. There are literally hundreds of plugins for this. E.g. Flexslider or slick.js.

Comment: If you wanna use jquery, there is a jquery-slider-plugin, which i would recommend to you: http://unslider.com/ Just initialize it with the parameter `{ infinite: true }` and you get your desired effect.

Comment: Sliders will display single div elements (slide1: DIV1, slide2: DIV2, etc.). But I don't want that. I want to display as many div elements as i can (depending on width of screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery `insertAfter` and `insertBefore` functions

```
$('.next').click(function(){
     var last = $('#parent').find('div').last();
    $('#parent').find('div').first().insertAfter(last);
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
     var first= $('#parent').find('div').first();
    $('#parent').find('div').last().insertBefore(first);
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/84u95mxe/)

Comment: please check my demo

Answer (score 5):

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append)/[prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend) the first/last element respectively depending on the direction you are going.

```js
jQuery(window).keyup(function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
     case 37: 
      left();
      break;
     case 39:
      right();
      break;
  }
})
var container=jQuery("#container");

function left(){
  container.find(".item:last").prependTo(container);
}

function right(){
  container.find(".item:first").appendTo(container);
}
```

```css
html,body {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
#container {
  width:100vw;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

.item {
  width:100px;
  height: 94px;
  margin:3px;
  flex:0 1 100px;
}

.red {background:#F00;}
.green {background:#0F0;}
.blue {background:#00F;}
.yellow {background:#FF0;}
.turq {background:#0FF;}
.purple {background:#F0F;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item turq"></div>
  <div class="item purple"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Works great.